# Custom Accordion transition animation not working on collapse and expand

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, accordion

I am trying to make a custom accordion structure in React. The content of the accordion gets rendered depending on some condition.**The issue is that the accordion content transition is not smooth**.

Two ways i tried to render the content

1. Remove and add div using tertiary operator depending upon the
   condition
2. Change style to display none depending upon the condition

In Both ways my Transition css does not work and the transition from showing to hiding seems off.

Here is the sample code of what i am trying to achieve

Approach1

```
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [cond, setCond] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Grid style={{ transition: "all 1s ease" }}>
      <Grid
        onClick={() => {
          setCond(!cond);
        }}
      >
        item 1
      </Grid>
      {cond ? (
        <Grid>
          item 2 content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
        </Grid>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Approach 2

```
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [cond, setCond] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Grid style={{ transition: "all 1s ease" }}>
      <Grid
        onClick={() => {
          setCond(!cond);
        }}
       >
        item 1
      </Grid>
      <Grid style={cond ? {} : { display: "none" }}>
        item 2 content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Here item 1 will be my accordion header
item 2 will be my accordion content

Answer (score 1):

Your code has comments and unnecessary lines, instead you should do this:

```
    <Grid 
    style={cond ? { display: "none" } : {}}
    >
      item 2 content Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    </Grid>
```

Another way of doing an accordtion is by using classes instead of inline styles (not recommended):

```
// js
import { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './App.module.css'; // your css file here
export default function App() {
    const [accordionState, setAccordtionState] = useState(false);
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.accordionWrapper}>
            <button onClick={() => setAccordionState(!accordionState)}>
                <span>Toggle item 1</span>
            </button>

            {/* accordion container */}
            <div className={styles.accordion} hidden={accordionState}>
                <span>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

// css
.accordion {
    height: 300px;
    transition: height 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion[hidden="true"] {
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: code updated with two different approaches